# Displaying SQL Query in TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity

Noob question

I'm currently writing an app in WPF connected to database made on Code First from Entity Framework. 
I want to make a query and then display the result in the TextBox.

This is my database context class:

```
class CepikDB : DbContext
{
    public CepikDB() : base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<CepikDB>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<CepikDB>());
    }
    public DbSet<Cars> Pojazdy { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Drivers> Kierowcy { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DrivingLicense> PrawoJazdy { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InsurancePolicy> Polisa { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TechnicalReview> BadanieTechniczne { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CarDocsAndInfo> Informacje { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I wanted to perform the query:

```
    using (var ctx = new CepikDB())
        {
            var driverList = ctx.Kierowcy
                .SqlQuery("Select * From Kierowcy")
                .ToList<Drivers>();
        }
```

However, I'm not sure how to display the result of the query in the textbox.

Comment: You know, you don't need to execute a raw SQL query, the whole point of having a DbSet is to insulate you from the SQL.

Comment: Thank you, I know, but I don't know what should I use instead of SQL. I tried LINQ but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the result to a string, something like this will work:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var driver in driverList)
{
    sb.AppendLine("$First name: {driver.FirstName}");
    sb.AppendLine("$Last name: {driver.LastName}");
}

string text = sb.ToString();
```

Then you could use the text variable to set the value of your text box.

But since you are using WPF, a List might be a better choice to visualize the result. Add this to your XAML:

```
    <ListView x:Name="MyList">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
                      "{Binding Path=FirstName}" 
                  Header="First Name" Width="100"/>

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
                      "{Binding Path=LastName}" 
                  Header="Last Name" Width="100">
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And then setup the list in the code behind with something like this:

```
MyList.ItemsSource = driverList;
```

Comment: It works! At first I had a problem with it but it was just my dumb mistake, thank you!